# Running total based on each record in a LINQ query for MVC ASP.net

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I'm running into two issues:

I tried assigning a ROW_NUMBER to my SQL view and do a running sum based on the row number (and therefore get the sums based on each record), but the resulting performance hit was quite noticeable.

I know how to do this in T-SQL for dates:

[image]

The `RunningTotal` column in this SQL statement is exactly what I need (itemized sums).

[image]

But it takes very long to execute.

**UPDATE 2** 
Here is how I created my second view.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vCI_UNIONALL_ROW] AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EffChkDt DESC) AS [Row]
    ,*
FROM vCI_UNIONALL
GO
```

My model:

```
public class UnionAllModel
{
    public int? InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public Decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? EffChkDt { get; set; }
    [omitted for clarity]
}
```

Here's my LINQ query so far:

```
using (var db = new PLOGITENS01Entities())
{
    var rvUnionAll = (from u in db.vCI_UNIONALL
                      orderby u.EffChkDt ascending
                      select new UnionAllModel()
                      {
                          InvoiceNumber = u.InvoiceNumber,
                          Date = u.Date,
                          AccountNumber = u.AccountNumber,
                          ClientName = u.ClientName,
                          Amount = u.Amount,
                          InAmount = u.InAmount,
                          OutAmount = u.OutAmount,
                          ClientRiskAdjs = u.ClientRiskAdjs,
                          SpecificAdjs = u.SpecificAdjs,
                          EffChkDt = u.EffChkDt,
                          PayStatus = u.PayStatus,
                          Type = u.Type
                      })
                     .ToList();

    return View(new GridModel(rvUnionAll));
}
```

Comment: Would you show how you are creating the `Row` column in the second view? You can do this in the client side, but knowing how you calculated `Row` is essential to that (if you used `Row_Number` you need to show the entire statement, what you ordered and partitioned on).

Comment: Hi, see update.  I simply did a ROW_NUMBER ordered on EffChkDt DESC upon my first view.  This allows me to get an itemized running sum.

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating the running sum adding the values to a local variable:

```
int runningSum = 0;
var rvUnionAll = (from u in db.vCI_UNIONALL.AsEnumerable()
                      orderby u.EffChkDt ascending
                      select new UnionAllModel()
                      {
                          InvoiceNumber = u.InvoiceNumber,
                          Date = u.Date,
                          AccountNumber = u.AccountNumber,
                          ClientName = u.ClientName,
                          Amount = u.Amount,
                          InAmount = u.InAmount,
                          OutAmount = u.OutAmount,
                          ClientRiskAdjs = u.ClientRiskAdjs,
                          SpecificAdjs = u.SpecificAdjs,
                          EffChkDt = u.EffChkDt,
                          PayStatus = u.PayStatus,
                          Type = u.Type,
                          RunningSum = runningSum += u.Amount
                      })
                     .ToList();
```